# Node3 is not getting involved in mutli-master-replication of 3nodes using symmetric-ds 3.10.0

Tags: symmetricds, multi-master-replication

I am trying to create multi-master replication for 3 nodes (servers) using symmetric ds 3.10.0. After configuring all the 3 nodes, the bi-directional replication is working perfectly between 1st and 2nd nodes. **But the bi-directional replication is NOT working between (node 1 and node3) / (node2 and node3).**

Node.properties for node1:

```
engine.name=master-1
group.id=master
external.id=1
db.driver=org.postgresql.Driver
db.url=jdbc:postgresql://192.40.40.1:5441/testdb
db.user=user1
db.password=postgres
registration.url=
sync.url=http://192.40.40.1:31415/sync/master-1
cluster.lock.enabled=false
job.purge.period.time.ms=7200000
job.routing.period.time.ms=5000
job.push.period.time.ms=10000
job.pull.period.time.ms=10000
auto.registration=true
initial.load.create.first=true
```

Node.properties for node2:

```
engine.name=master-002
group.id=master
external.id=002
db.driver=org.postgresql.Driver
db.url=jdbc:postgresql://192.40.40.2:5441/testdb
db.user=user1
db.password=postgres
registration.url=http://192.40.40.1:31415/sync/master-1
sync.url=http://192.40.40.2:31415/sync/master-002
cluster.lock.enabled=false
job.routing.period.time.ms=5000
job.push.period.time.ms=10000
auto.registration=true
job.pull.period.time.ms=10000
```

Node.properties for node3:

```
engine.name=master-003
group.id=master
external.id=003
db.driver=org.postgresql.Driver
db.url=jdbc:postgresql://192.40.40.3:5441/testdb
db.user=user1
db.password=postgres
registration.url=http://192.40.40.1:31415/sync/master-1
sync.url=http://192.40.40.3:31415/sync/master-003
cluster.lock.enabled=false
job.routing.period.time.ms=5000
job.push.period.time.ms=10000
job.pull.period.time.ms=10000
auto.registration=true
```

The following sql queries are executed at node1 after creating sym_tables:

```
INSERT INTO sym_node_group (node_group_id, description, create_time, last_update_by, last_update_time) VALUES ('master', 'The one group in a master to master cluster', NULL, NULL, NULL);
INSERT INTO "public".sym_node_group_link (source_node_group_id, target_node_group_id, data_event_action, sync_config_enabled, is_reversible, create_time, last_update_by, last_update_time) VALUES ('master', 'master', 'P', 1, 0, NULL, NULL, NULL);
INSERT INTO "public".sym_router (router_id, target_catalog_name, target_schema_name, target_table_name, source_node_group_id, target_node_group_id, router_type, router_expression, sync_on_update, sync_on_insert, sync_on_delete, use_source_catalog_schema, create_time, last_update_by, last_update_time, description) VALUES ('master_2_master', NULL, NULL, NULL, 'master', 'master', 'default', NULL, 1, 1, 1, 0, '2022-05-01 11:41:03.738169', 'console', '2022-05-01 11:41:03.738169', NULL);
```

All required rows are inserted into `sym_trigger` and `sym_trigger_router` tables as well.

symmteric.log  file in node3:

```
2022-01-06 16:58:45,903 INFO [master-002] [PushService] [master-002-push-default-3] Push data sent to master:003:003
2022-01-06 16:58:45,912 WARN [master-002] [PushService] [master-002-push-default-3] Registration is needed before communicating with master:003:003
2022-01-06 16:58:45,912 INFO [master-002] [PushService] [master-002-push-default-3] Removing identity because registration is required
2022-01-06 16:58:45,950 ERROR [master-002] [DataExtractorService] [master-002-push-default-4] Failed to extract batch 1-4 StackTraceKey.init [NullPointerException:3940683079]
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.jumpmind.symmetric.service.impl.DataExtractorService.sendOutgoingBatch(DataExtractorService.java:1414)
    at org.jumpmind.symmetric.service.impl.DataExtractorService.extract(DataExtractorService.java:769)
    at org.jumpmind.symmetric.service.impl.DataExtractorService.extract(DataExtractorService.java:559)
    at org.jumpmind.symmetric.service.impl.PushService.pushToNode(PushService.java:206)
    at org.jumpmind.symmetric.service.impl.PushService.execute(PushService.java:167)
    at org.jumpmind.symmetric.service.impl.NodeCommunicationService$1.run(NodeCommunicationService.java:519)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
2022-01-06 16:58:45,954 INFO [master-002] [PushService] [master-002-push-default-4] Push data sent to master:1:1
2022-01-06 16:58:45,973 INFO [master-002] [PushService] [master-002-push-default-4] Pushed data to node master:1:1. 1 data and 1 batches were processed. (sym_node)
2022-01-06 16:58:45,974 ERROR [master-002] [NodeCommunicationService] [master-002-push-default-4] Failed to execute PUSH for node 1 and channel default StackTraceKey.init [NullPointerException:2481146486]
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.jumpmind.symmetric.service.impl.PushService.pushToNode(PushService.java:195)
    at org.jumpmind.symmetric.service.impl.PushService.execute(PushService.java:167)
    at org.jumpmind.symmetric.service.impl.NodeCommunicationService$1.run(NodeCommunicationService.java:519)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
2022-01-06 16:58:54,351 INFO [master-002] [RegistrationService] [master-002-job-6] This node is unregistered.  It will attempt to register using the registration.url
2022-01-06 16:58:54,395 INFO [master-002] [DataLoaderService] [master-002-job-6] Using registration URL of http://192.40.40.1:31415/sync/master-1/registration?nodeGroupId=master&externalId=002&syncURL=http%3A%2F%2F192.40.40.3%3A31415%2Fsync%2Fmaster-002&schemaVersion=%3F&databaseType=PostgreSQL&databaseVersion=9.6&symmetricVersion=3.10.0&deploymentType=server&hostName=MY_PC&ipAddress=192.40.40.3
2022-01-06 16:58:54,505 INFO [master-002] [DataService] [master-002-dataloader-3] Deleted 1 data rows that were on the config channel
2022-01-06 16:58:55,333 INFO [master-002] [ConfigurationChangedDatabaseWriterFilter] [master-002-dataloader-3] Grouplets flushed because new grouplet config came through the data loader
2022-01-06 16:58:55,333 INFO [master-002] [ConfigurationChangedDatabaseWriterFilter] [master-002-dataloader-3] Load filters flushed because new filter config came through the data loader
2022-01-06 16:58:55,333 INFO [master-002] [ConfigurationChangedDatabaseWriterFilter] [master-002-dataloader-3] Channels flushed because new channels came through the data loader
2022-01-06 16:58:55,333 INFO [master-002] [ConfigurationChangedDatabaseWriterFilter] [master-002-dataloader-3] About to refresh the cache of conflict settings because new configuration came through the data loader
2022-01-06 16:58:55,333 INFO [master-002] [ConfigurationChangedDatabaseWriterFilter] [master-002-dataloader-3] About to refresh the cache of parameters because new configuration came through the data loader
2022-01-06 16:58:55,340 INFO [master-002] [ConfigurationChangedDatabaseWriterFilter] [master-002-dataloader-3] About to refresh the cache of node security because new configuration came through the data loader
2022-01-06 16:58:55,341 INFO [master-002] [ConfigurationChangedDatabaseWriterFilter] [master-002-job-6] About to refresh the cache of transformation because new configuration came through the data loader
2022-01-06 16:58:55,341 INFO [master-002] [ConfigurationChangedDatabaseWriterFilter] [master-002-job-6] About to clear the staging area because new transform configuration came through the data loader
2022-01-06 16:58:55,341 INFO [master-002] [StagingManager] [master-002-job-6] Cleaning staging...
2022-01-06 16:58:55,345 INFO [master-002] [StagingManager] [master-002-job-6] Purged 6 staging files, freed 50 KB of disk space.
2022-01-06 16:58:55,345 INFO [master-002] [StagingManager] [master-002-job-6] Finished cleaning staging in 0 seconds.
2022-01-06 16:58:55,345 INFO [master-002] [ConfigurationChangedDatabaseWriterFilter] [master-002-job-6] About to syncTriggers because new configuration came through the data loader
2022-01-06 16:58:55,345 INFO [master-002] [TriggerRouterService] [master-002-job-6] Synchronizing triggers
2022-01-06 16:58:55,913 INFO [master-002] [PushService] [master-002-push-default-6] Push data sent to master:1:1
2022-01-06 16:58:55,918 WARN [master-002] [PushService] [master-002-push-default-6] Registration is needed before communicating with master:1:1
2022-01-06 16:58:55,918 INFO [master-002] [PushService] [master-002-push-default-6] Removing identity because registration is required
2022-01-06 16:58:55,961 ERROR [master-002] [DataExtractorService] [master-002-push-default-5] Failed to extract batch 003-5 StackTraceKey [NullPointerException:3940683079]
2022-01-06 16:58:55,962 INFO [master-002] [PushService] [master-002-push-default-5] Push data sent to master:003:003
2022-01-06 16:58:55,966 WARN [master-002] [PushService] [master-002-push-default-5] Registration is needed before communicating with master:003:003
2022-01-06 16:58:55,966 INFO [master-002] [PushService] [master-002-push-default-5] Removing identity because registration is required
And so on...
......
......
```

Comment: Have you tried configuring sync on incoming batch as explained in the chapter on bi-directional synchronization https://www.jumpmind.com/downloads/symmetricds/doc/3.10/html/user-guide.html#_bi_directional_synchronization

Comment: @BorisPavlović yes, but of no use (in my case).

Comment: I would checkout the source code of this version of SymmetricDS, import it to an IDE (IntelliJ IDEA), set a breakpoint in the method that throws an exception, configure the Java process executing the node3 to start in remote debug mode with a certain debug port open, let’s say 5005, start the server, run the IDE in remote debug mode connecting to the IP address of the host node3 is running on and the port 5005, initiate the synchronization and observe in the IDE what’s the missing object that causes a NullPointerException

Comment: @BorisPavlović That's amazing.... Please do it for me...:)

Comment: It’s not that hard as it looks, believe me

Comment: @Boris Pavlović,  Did you find any clue?

Comment: Have you tried remote debugging?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240858/discussion-between-svkvvenky-and-boris-pavlovic).

Comment: My issue got resolved. There is a bug in symmetric ds 3.10.0. w.r.t registration of a node. I tried with symmetric ds 3.12.2. and the issue got resolved.